# What does the Goat Head do?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

Twice now, I've picked up the Goat head item, but I can't tell what it does. The item description just says "He accepts your offering." So, what does it do?

Answer (score 3):

The wiki is partially correct, but not entirely. From my own personal exploration, I can confirm that an angel/devil room WILL spawn after EVERY boss fight where one can, however it does NOT block damage from above.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Gamepedia wiki for BoI Rebirth](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Goat_Head):

> No damage will be taken from directly above. This includes jumping enemies and Mom's foot. Devil Room spawns after every boss fight.

Comment: I wouldn't trust the wiki at this point in time, though.

Comment: @No.7892142 I wouldn't either, but no damage from above would be crazy powerful for those new master/mom hands, as well as for mom herself ofc. Heck, jumping enemies are one of my more common ways to lose hearts, so it'd be great for them too.

Answer (score -2):

The effect that I have experienced with the goat's head is that after taking damage that eliminates a soul heart, all remaining enemies in the room die. I have yet to test this on a boss and this only works with soul hearts.

Comment: I think that's actually the black hearts, which are different.

Answer (score -6):

I figured it out: If an enemy touches you, it turns them into poop.

Comment: thats e-coli, not the goat head

Comment: This is incorrect.